# How to calculate backplane throughput given an arbitrary list of network links?

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

Given a device (router lets say) that can take an arbitrary number of network connections how much backplane throughput should be allocated to a given set of network connections.

(we assume all of these are symmetrical, and further to simplify the discussion we assume we're only counting each interface once, instead of once for TX and a second time for RX)

Also we assume traffic is always TRANSITING the router, never destined to it directly.  So any packets that come in one interface must leave another.  There is no "loopback" function here.

examples:

a single 1G link.  It can't send any traffic to anywhere so backplane allocation is ZERO.

two 1G links.  one can perfectly saturate the other, so total backplane allocation should be 1000mbps.

a single 1G link and a single 50M link.  total allocation is 50mbps since the most traffic the 1G link would ever be able to send is 50mbps.

My intuitive assumption is there must be a "simple" formula to get this, something easily suitable for an excel spreadsheet or the like, but I haven't been able to come up with anything.

The mental algorithm I use to come up with the "right" answer is  essentially picking the biggest link, stack the others against it until it's "saturated", then repeating with the next largest remaining link, etc.  any throughput left over from the last interface at the end is discarded.

Here's the test cases I've come up with, my official answer, and the various results I get from the various strategies I've tried.

| case | My answer | sum | sum / 2 | 'sum the minimums of the sorted pairs' | sum - max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4x50m | 100 | 200 | 100 | 100 | 150 |
| 1x100,3x50 | 100 | 250 | 125 | 100 | 150 |
| 2x125, 2x50 | 175 | 350 | 175 | 175 | 225 |
| 1x1000,2x200,1x50 | 450 | 1450 | 725 | 250 | 450 |

Comment: sum/2 is the theoretic maximum possible, and you want the largest number you can make less than or equal to it using the cables.

Comment: I didn't think this was excel related until I saw table at end -- would this be one for Superuser instead perhaps (I don't actually know)..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Revision**: Thanks to help from [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) and
> [EDS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10962789/eds) in this connected
> [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69067988/parse-a-string-into-a-table-using-filterxml),
> I have added a way to accept the text inputs shown in the Cases from
> your examples.

To get the correct backplane bandwidth, you need to find the right combination of connections that will total to half of the aggregate bandwidth. For example, if you had connections of `1,2, ... ,6`, you are looking for any combination that adds to `21/2=10`. e.g., `6,4` gets you there.

i.e., ***the correct answer will approach the half of the sum of all bandwidth***. While ***sum/2*** would provide a quick & dirty approximation, it can be wildly off if the number of connections is small and their make-up is asymmetrical. e.g. the case that you presented as `1x1000,2x200,1x50` has a backplane bandwidth of 450 - far from 725.

To get to the correct answer in all cases, requires some form of iteration, which is not supported in Excel functions. You can create real iteration through LAMBDA recursion (not yet released) or VBA. But there is also another way: iteration can be emulated through functions that contain iterations.

You can imagine this as a method of *'folding'*.  What we are trying to do is to put the connections on either side of a piece of paper and fold the paper where the left and right side numbers cancel each other.  The sum of the numbers that get canceled are the backplane bandwidth. The residual is waste. For example: connections of speeds 1,2,3,4,5, and 6, would have 4 & 6 on the left side and 2, 3, & 5 on the right. The 1 has no match and becomes residual, like this:
[image: folding example]

There are obviously `2^6-2=62` possible arrangements on the paper and we have to find the one that best balances them.  I came up with two approaches which I will call:

- **Brute-force Folding** : create *every possible fold* and search for the one that gets half the summation on a single side.
- **Adaptive Folding** : sort the connections, make an initial fold and use it to determine the next fold, rinse, repeat.

Brute-force is achievable as a LET formula without iteration. Adaptive works, but requires iteration or possibly recursion, so it would only be possible with a LAMBDA or VBA UDF tmk.

### Forming the Input

**Connection Array**

In all cases we need to normalize the input into an array of connection speeds. e.g.:

[image: connection array]

That's probably not the best user interface for the formula because it would be tedious and take up a lot of cells to write all those out. So there are two possible alternatives:

**Connection Table**

| Connections | of Speed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1050 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 50 |

**Comma Delimited Strings** *-as you showed in your example*

`1x1050,2x400,1x200,1x100,1x50`

So, the front part of the formula will simply form the input into a Connection Array.

The rest focuses on the calculation mechanics.

## Brute-Force Folding

Using a Connection Table as input, you can do:

```
=LET( connectionTable, A2:B6,
       connections, INDEX(connectionTable,,1), speeds, INDEX(connectionTable,,2),
       elements, SUM( connections ),  eSeq, SEQUENCE( elements,,0 ),
       bySeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( connections ) ),
       byPos, MMULT( --(bySeq >= TRANSPOSE( bySeq )), connections ),
       conx, INDEX( speeds, IFERROR(MATCH( eSeq, byPos, 1 )+1,1)  ),
       bpBW, LET( array, conx,
                  r, ROWS( array ), c, 2^(r-1)-1, s, SUM(array),
                  cSeq, SEQUENCE(1,c,1),
                  idx, MOD(SEQUENCE(r,c,0),c)+1, e, 2^SEQUENCE(r,,r-1,-1), foldArray, MOD(INT(idx/e),2),
                  p, MMULT( SIGN( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( foldArray ) ) ), array*foldArray ), n, s - p,
                  c2z, MATCH( MIN( ABS( p-n ) ), ABS( p-n ), 0 ),
                  result, MIN( INDEX( CHOOSE( {1;2}, p, n ), , c2z ) ),
                   result  ),
       bpBW )
```

Where **connectionTable** is a table containing the number of connections of each speed as described above. Here is an illustration of `1x1050,2x400,1x100,1x50` which will yield a backplane bandwidth of 1100 with no residual. It effectively puts 1050 and 50 on one page and the rest on the other.

[image: example of Brute Force]

### Notes

I nested the LETs and broke out their results of **result** and **bpBW** to make it easier to inspect each part. This can be consolidate further, but that would make it harder to optimize and understand.  The calculations can also be simplified a little bit by using **s/2** instead of creating an **n** array, but that makes it harder to explain and to break out and examine, so I did left this formula in its most readable and understandable format even if it is quite long.

### How it works

The first LET starts by reshaping the Connection Table input into a Connection Array which is an expanded list of connection speeds.

[image: illustration of formula sections]

The second LET is the takes the **array** from the first LET and calculates the **bpBW** (backplane bandwidth) as **result**.

It does this by generating an array of binary representations of each possible fold called the **foldArray**. It then multiplies this times **array** to create a matrix of values and that matrix is summed column-wise to create a single-row array called **p** or the positive side of the fold. It also calculated **n**, the negative side of the fold by taking **s** (the sum of all connections) - **p**.  *(This can be simplified and eliminated by using **s/2** as a reference, but I kept **n** in place for inspection to understand how the approach actually works.)*

Now that we have both sides of the fold, the residuals can be calculated as `ABS( p - n )`. We are looking for the column with lowest residual or "closest to zero" **c2z**. At that column, we need to take the smaller of the **p** and **n** values. That min is the backplane bandwidth.

### Putting it All Together

This diagram shows how it works.  The blue sections are showing how the inputs can be shaped into a Connection Array and the green section shows how the computations are rendered.

[image: all pieces together]

### Variations on Inputs

The version above accepts a **Connection Table** as input.  Here are different versions of the formula for each possible way that you might want to accept the input:

**Connection Array**

```
=LET( array, A2:A7,
         r, ROWS( array ), c, 2^(r-1)-1, s, SUM(array),
         cSeq, SEQUENCE(1,c,1),
         idx, MOD(SEQUENCE(r,c,0),c)+1, e, 2^SEQUENCE(r,,r-1,-1), foldArray, MOD(INT(idx/e),2),
         p, MMULT( SIGN( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( foldArray ) ) ), array*foldArray ),
         c2z, MATCH( MIN( ABS( s/2-p ) ), ABS( s/2-p ), 0 ),
         bpBW, MIN( INDEX( CHOOSE( {1;2}, p, s-p ), , c2z ) ),
       bpBW )
```

**Comma Delimited** e.g. "1x100,2x500,3x200"

```
=LET( case, A11,
       x, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A11,",","x"),"x","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),
       connectionTable, INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(COUNT(x)/2,2)),
       connections, INDEX(connectionTable,,1), speeds, INDEX(connectionTable,,2),
       elements, SUM( connections ),  eSeq, SEQUENCE( elements,,0 ),
       bySeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( connections ) ),
       byPos, MMULT( --(bySeq >= TRANSPOSE( bySeq )), connections ),
       conx, INDEX( speeds, IFERROR(MATCH( eSeq, byPos, 1 )+1,1)  ),
       bpBW, LET( array, conx,
                   r, ROWS( array ), c, 2^(r-1)-1, s, SUM(array),
                   cSeq, SEQUENCE(1,c,1),
                   idx, MOD(SEQUENCE(r,c,0),c)+1, e, 2^SEQUENCE(r,,r-1,-1), foldArray, MOD(INT(idx/e),2),
                   p, MMULT( SIGN( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( foldArray ) ) ), array*foldArray ),
                   c2z, MATCH( MIN( ABS( s/2-p ) ), ABS( s/2-p ), 0 ),
                   result, MIN( INDEX( CHOOSE( {1;2}, p, s-p ), , c2z ) ),
                    result  ),
       bpBW )
```

And here are the results applied to an extended version of your cases:

| case | Brute-force |
| --- | --- |
| 4x50 | 100 |
| 1x100,3x50 | 100 |
| 2x125, 2x50 | 175 |
| 1x1000,2x200,1x50 | 450 |
| 1x1050,2x400,1x200,1x100,1x50 | 1100 |
| 1x1050,2x400,1x150,1x100,1x50 | 1050 |
| 2x1000,2x200,1x50,1x100 | 1250 |
| 1x200,3x125,4x400,3x1000,2x2000 | 4575 |
| 1x130,1x270,1x410,1x390,1x300,1x120 | 810 |
| 1x170,2x270,1x210 | 440 |
| 1x130,1x270,1x180,1x220 | 400 |

## Adaptive Folding

It would be a lot of work to fully describe adaptive folding or build it in VBA and I think the above answers your question already, so I will keep this brief.

The problem with the Brute Force approach is that it computes all possible arrangements.  A 16 port device would have a 524,272 cell array. 24 ports is 201 million, 32 is 68 billion, and 48 port would be 6.8 quadrillion. When you reach such levels SUM/2 is probably already a good enough approximation, but if you really had to have a correct answer, Brute-Forcing it would break your machine.

So an alternative is to search for the best-fit combination of connections that form SUM/2 of aggregate bandwidth without 'boiling the ocean'. The method is:

1. Sort the Connection Array - descending.
2. Start subtracting elements 2... to X from element 1 until the sum is <= 0. Then set a variable B to equal the sum of the bandwidth of elements 2... X - Residual (if there is any).
3. Go to element X+1 and add the Residual and then repeat Step 2 above by adding the new B to the old B.
   Keep repeating 2 and 3 until all connections have been reviewed. B is the answer.

This reduces a 48 port connection from a 6.8 quadrillion array to at-most a 48^2 array and 47 iterations. In all likelihood, the algorithm will end in less than 10 iterations on such a large device.

Comment: That's a ton to process!  I'll go through it in the morning, but so far it seems like if nothing else we've proven my prior assertion wrong:  'there must be a "simple" formula to get this, something easily suitable for an excel spreadsheet or the like'.  Perhaps there's a simpler formulation of the problem?  something we could hold constant to make everything else simpler?

Comment: @WilliamGeorge - the problem is that the algorithm requires iteration which is normally done by a UDF. I thought of a way to simplify the calculation, but it just removes one trivial step (cutting calcs by 50%). The blue boxes are decoration. They are simply shaping the input to make the formula easier to use. The green part is the algorithm and the only reason it works is because it avoids iteration. Adaptive folding has even more process because of iteration, but has at least an order of magnitude less computation. Try it on tricky cases like `1x130,1x270,1x180,1x220`. It works.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge - I finally had the time to put the description in place. It explains why a non-iterative approach will only ever give an approximation. By using the Brute-Force formula above, you can now create experiments on a large scale and compare different approximation approaches to the correct result with real-world data. The short answer is that the correct result will always approximate and never exceed sum/2.

Comment: This absolutely solves my need as-is.  I need a tool we can use to ensure we're not overcommitting this scarce resource (backplane throughput).  Reading through the analysis though, I see a parallel with the much broader question of throughput across our entire backbone network.  That's definitely is a case that might call for a more efficient adaptive folding approach.  I'd previously written that problem off as "more or less unsolvable", and previously relied on very vague napkin math.  I very well might take your description here and take it down that road.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @WilliamGeorge I'm really glad it works for you. The problem is one of those where you think there is no solution and then realize a few minutes later that there could be so you keep coming back to it. When I was doing backbone traffic engineering, the practice was simply to provision 2 x aggregate which I found to be expensive and wasteful. However, bandwidth demand was growing so fast that my objections were trivial. I imagine this has changed and BB sizing is now critical. When LAMBDA is released, I will try Adaptive and ping you here. It would be an interesting use case for LAMBDA.